# kendo grid with edit, delete and custom command

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid

I want to implement a kendo ui js grid with delete, edit and a custom command button. 
I did it by doing this:

```
   {
            command: [
            { text: "Edit", template: "<a class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit'>Edit</a>" }, { text: "Delete", template: "<a class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Delete'>Delete</a>" }, { text: "Translate", click: translateFeatures }], width: 250
        }
```

the only problem here is when i want to add a new row it works good as expected except that the edit button doesn't become an updatebutton as it does if i
would have used this code:

```
  { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
```

is there a way to implement the standard edit and destroy buttons and still have the save functionality when creating a new row?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the "name" property with the according command name (edit, destroy) to the first 2 commands it should work. Also it seems your templates are useless given they are already the default templates for these actions...